# Correct way to use TypeScript and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I would like to use RequireJS in combination with TypeScript. In my `index.html` file I included the following line (look at the `data-main` attribute):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/require.js" data-main="build/main.js"></script>
```

I use the `require.config` method to instruct RequireJs where to find my libraries. My `main.ts` script looks as follows:

```
/// <reference path="path/to/MyPackage.d.ts" />
require.config({ paths: {'MyPackage': 'path/to/MyPackage'}});
import {MyClass} from 'MyPackage';

new MyClass();
```

And the TypeScript compiler generates something like this:

```
define(['require', 'exports', 'MyClass'], function (require, export, MyClass_1) {
  ...
  require.config({ paths: {'MyPackage': 'path/to/MyPackage'}});
  var t = new MyClass_1();
});
```

But the previous compiled code generates the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function

That's because the `require.config` function shouldn't be inside the `define([...], ...` function. If I move the `require.config` function outside the `define` function, all works well.

**Additional notes**:

I declared my application as a AMD module (tsconfig.json):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "amd",
     ... more directives ...
```

I solved this problem by using this approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27166031/1704895

But I'm not very satisfied with that solution. It looks like a bit tricky. How would you solve this problem?