# TypeScript dynamic loading of AMD module ends in "Could not find symbol '...'

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, requirejs, typescript, amd

No, this topic won't answer my question and NO, the solution is not simply importing `Command` in the nav.ts file. nav.ts is one of many viewModel-files and they will be loaded dynamically on demand. The only problem is to set the parameter's type in the constructor of the class. (Type has to be "Command")

---

In the following class, which will be loaded by require.js, the method `viewModel()` requires a new class dynamically. In this case  `NavViewModel` .

***command.ts***

```
export class Command {
```

...

```
    public viewModel(name: string, callback: Function) {
        require(["noext!boot/getViewModel/" + name], function (viewModel) {
            callback(viewModel);
        });
    }
}
```

This is the class which will be fetched by `viewModel()`:

***nav.ts***

```
export class NavViewModel extends kendo.Router {
    constructor(command: Command) {
        super();

        this.route('/:name', function (name) {
            command.view(name, $('div.content'));
        });

        this.start();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the entry-point (requested in comment 2)

***main.ts*** (EntryPoint)

```
import lib = require("command");

var cmd = new lib.Command();
cmd.viewModel('nav', function (o) {
    cmd.view('nav', $('div.header'), function () {
        kendo.bind($('.header .nav'), new o.NavViewModel(cmd));
    });
});
```

**/EDIT**

**The Problem:**

Visual Studio will throw the `error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Command'`, because the "Command" class ist not defined in this Module.

The program works fine if the "Command"-Type will be removed from the `NavViewModel` constructor. Is there any solution to reference the Command class in the NavViewModel?

This won't work:

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/command.ts" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import other TypeScript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930049/how-do-i-import-other-typescript-files)

Comment: You should show the code for how you define your modules. Is the Command class in a different Module than your NavViewModel class? If so, you need to reference the entire name (ex. `command: Your.Module.Name.Command`).

Comment: I've added the snippet, which shows the entry-point.

Comment: @Louis Thanks, but I don't think it's a duplicate question, because the linked examples doesn't load another module dynamically on runtime..

Comment: I've never used TypeScript but on the basis of the question I linked to, I'd expect ``nav.ts`` to have a statement importing the ``command`` module (loading ``command.ts``). Moreover, you show us code referring to the ``Command`` class in ``nav.ts`` as ``Command``. How can this work? Surely you have to access through the symbol name of the module you import *exactly like you do in the ``main.ts`` snippet you've added.*

Comment: It works, because NavViewModel will get the current instance of command in main.ts. And no, I don't have to import command.ts again because as I told already, NavViewModel will be required dynamically on runtime out of Command.viewModel() and will get the instance of Command as constructor-param in the callback. As I wrote, the script works fine, but the compiler will cry when i define the constructor parameter's type: ```constructor(command: Command)``` won't compile -> but ```constructor(command)``` will.

Comment: All I want is to define the type of the parameter like: ```constructor(command: Command)```. If you've added "This question may already have an answer here:", please remove it, because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ok, you need to make the argument to the constructor of NavViewMain an Interface ( ie ICommand), not a concrete class, and have your Command class implement that interface.  Every viewModel class will need to reference the Interface, this way you can ditch the need for the import

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to define an Interface, but I'll try again, because I defined the Interface with the same name (Command). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RequireJS, the import statement should be the full path from the *root* of the application.

I also use a slightly different export syntax

**command.ts**

```
class command {
    ...
}

export = command;
```

**main.ts**

```
// I'm assuming the Scripts folder is at the root of the application
import Command = require('Scripts/command');

var cmd = new Command();
```

**Note**

I'm using Typescript 0.9.1.1.  I can't upgrade my machine to 0.9.5 as a large internal application is affected by some breaking changes between versions

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I wrote (about 4 times), the script will be loaded dynamically at runtime, so import is no option. At time of compilation it is unclear which viewModels will be loaded. The script works fine, I only wanna know if I can tell VS that the command parameter's type of NavViewModel is "Command", without importing the Command object in every viewModel.

Comment: Then I have completely misunderstood your question as it was posted when I replied.  Further edit's have changed the nature of the problem.  The error is being thrown in nav.ts, not main.ts ?