# Setting up TypeScript / Angular with Gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, gulp, browserify

Very familiar with Gulp and Angular, new to TypeScript. I have been using Browserify to bundle my JavaScript and manage the dependency tree but as I understand it I won't want to use Browserify alongside TypeScript.

Before I would have something like this in my main/entry point file.

```
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('./myModules/testModule')
require('./myControllers/mainController')

angular.module('exampleApp', ['mainController','testModule'])

    .config(...);

}());
```

This would insure all of the necessary files were bundled into the final `.js` app in the appropriate order.

However with TypeScript (using gulp-typescript) the way to reference other files for building seems to be:

```
/// <reference path="myModule.ts"/>)
```

But this only works for other TypeScript files.  How would I load my `angular` and other non TS deps?

For reference, my build looks like:

```
var jsStream = function() {
    return gulp.src(PUBLIC + '/js/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(typescript({
            declarationFiles: false,
            sortOutput: true,
            out: 'app.js'
        }))
        .pipe( streamify( rev() ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( PATHS.dest.js ) );
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but this seems to be an answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12930871/2148667

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript references like `/// <reference path="myModule.ts"/>` are used for transpilation to JS, resolving dependencies, as well as for Intellisense in a text editor or IDE. If you have existing libraries that you wish to reference in your TypeScript that aren't written in TypeScript, look no further than [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd) and the [DefinitelyTyped project](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) on GitHub.

You can still use Browserify to bundle like you did before. The only difference is you need to transpile your TypeScript to JavaScript first via `tsc` or as you mentioned `gulp-typescript`. Once you have your TS as JS, bundle if with your other files like angular with Browserify. I have no idea if this plugin is any good, but there appears to be a TypeScript Browserify plugin called [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify). Maybe check that out as well.

Comment: I know this is an older post but was a solution reached on getting tsify to work with angular?  I can't seem to get my main file (index.ts) to load the module.

    //#### Type Definitions ####
    /// <reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
    
    import angular = require('angular');
    angular.module('app', []);