# how to import js file in typescript project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to import a `js` library(`react-native-webview-bridge`) in my react-native project.but my project use `typescript`,and the library is `js`.when i import it, it tips '[ts] connot find module `react-native-webview-bridge`'.so i want to know how to transfer js to `typescript`,or other way to deal it.thanks!

```
import * as WebView from 'react-native-webview-bridge'
```

Answer (score 1):

from their GitHub  i understand you need change  the 'WebView' to 'WebViewBridge'.

** CommonJS style **

`var WebViewBridge = require('react-native-webview-bridge');`

** ES6/ES2015 style **

`import WebViewBridge from 'react-native-webview-bridge';`

Comment: thanks for you answer.but my project use typescript, not javascript,so cannot import directly.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930049/how-do-i-import-other-typescript-files

Comment: You can also use require `require("script!../lib/d3.js");` inside your typescript.

Comment: your mean is?
var webView = require('script!react-native-webview-bridge')