# Typescript doesn't resolve modules correctly after compiling to the js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I set the property paths in the tsconfig.json file, like:

```
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "*",
    "src/*",
    "node_modules/*"
  ],
  "src/*": [ "./src/*" ]
},
```

And it gets me to be able to take some module more easy:
e.g.

```
- src
  |- moduleA
  |- utils
    |- moduleB

// moduleA
import { something } from 'utils/moduleB'
```

but after compile I get next path in the moduleB.js:

```
something = require('utils/moduleB')
```

instead of relative path:

```
something = require('./utils/moduleB')
```

It doesn't work under Node because Node module resolution system knows nothing about utils folder.

So, how can I force tsc to use relative paths here?

Upd:
Here is the real example the one of my resulting js file:

[image]

data & utils they are the inner and not externals modules. My question is why tsc doesn't resolve them according to the baseUrl in the compiled files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import other TypeScript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930049/how-do-i-import-other-typescript-files)

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't solve my problem. I want to have got relative paths in the resulting js file.

Comment: @yiooxir have you found the solution?