# Electron and typescript "Cannot find module 'electron'"

Tags: typescript, electron

Regarding https://electron.atom.io/blog/2017/06/01/typescript
electron support typescript but is not working on my setup:

[image: [ts] cannot find module 'electron']

I use vscode 1.16.1

Here is my package.json

```
{
  [...]
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.13",
    "ts-loader": "~2.3.7",
    "typescript": "~2.5.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    [...]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

and my webpack

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [{
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'electron',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'electron_core.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}  
];
```

When I add at the top of my main.ts

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts" />
```

then is ok I don't have the error anymore. However I would like to avoid referencing files like this as it seems it's useless with the latest version of typescript (see [How do I import other TypeScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930049/how-do-i-import-other-typescript-files?answertab=votes#tab-top)) and moreover in the electron tutorial for typescript they don't need it ...)

Thanks

Comment: Does adding `"moduleResolution": "node"` to `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` section help?

Comment: Totally ! Woah I struggle long time for this missing line ! Thank you a lot ! Maybe you could answer to my question instead of commenting so I can set your answer as the valid answer :-)

Comment: Moved that to answer:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the way `tsc` (and `tsserver`) resoves modules [by default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

To use use node.js-like algorithm you need to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to `"compilerOptions"` section of `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue.
import { shell } from "electron"; //Give "Cannot find module 'electron'"

I also made the changes suggested above in tsconfig.json file.

Please help if anyone have the proper solution of this error.

Answer (score 3):

Having the exact same issue here.
It also affects code completion in the VS Code since it cannot find the "electron" module.

This happens because electron does not exist in the node_module folder.

If I do `npm install electron --save-dev`, it fixes the issue.

Comment: This works in case electron is not installed and if we try run Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

Using `node@12` is a temporary fix in case this issue is caused by [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21612) bug rather than any of the other ones mentioned above.