# In TypeScript , how to use a class located in another file

Tags: typescript

I'm a little confused with typescript namespaces , modules . I need to solve a simple task - create two typescript files and use a class from one in another.
But , how do I get it working.

The structure :

```
 installation :
          typescript :
                Person.ts
                main.ts
```

The code of main.ts is

```
//Using this tag I am trying to load another file
/// <reference path = "Person.ts" />

var person:Person = new Person("Sergey" , "Sckoriy");
console.log(person.greet());
```

The code of Person.ts is

```
export class Person {
    name : string;
    surname : string;

    constructor (name : string , surname : string){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    greet():string {
        var text:string = "Hello" + this.name;
        return text;
    }
}
```

But , when it's being compiled with

```
  ..../tsc main.ts
```

there are errors such as :

```
main.ts:3:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Person'.
3 var person:Person = new Person("Sergey" , "Sckoriy");
main.ts:3:25 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Person'. Did you mean 'person'?
3 var person:Person = new Person("Sergey" , "Sckoriy");
main.ts:3:5
3 var person:Person = new Person("Sergey" , "Sckoriy");
      ~~~~~~
'person' is declared here.

 Found 2 errors.
```

Actually , I have refered another file with the tag but it's not working...Whats wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import other TypeScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930049/how-do-i-import-other-typescript-files)

Comment: That question references a class and a module, but the solution is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import { Person } from './Person`

Comment: I have already tried this solution early , but the compiler said cannot find module Person. I have typed - import {Person} from 'Person'  . And , I can' realize why have you used both a dot and a slash before Person?

Comment: Please , explain , how to import not only one class but all classes from './Person'?

Comment: The ./ is to refer a relative path from your current folder. Else it’ll search from the root of your folder. Importing all can be done as `import * from ‘./person’`, but you will need to namespace it. A better convention is to specifically import what you need, so a compiler can decide what to take with in the final product and therefore end up with smaller files.